# How redirect with multiple route?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, redirect, roles

I have in my app two dashboards. One for admin and an other for teacher.
My question is the next,
How can i redirect on to a component and the other in the other component ? if you have an example of code it's better ahahah.

I'm a beginner in this domain.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BrowserRouter` if you're using react router v4 and implement your app navigation like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/teacher" component={Teacher} />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Hence your corresponding components will be rendered. I hope this made all clear.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create a link that redirect to other component home page

```
<a href={{route('teacher dashboard route name)}}>Teacher Dashboard</a>
 <a href={{route('admin dashboard route name)}}>Admin Dashboard</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is to redirect after a login. Some users avec the role of teacher and the user admin so in juste ```<a href={{route('teacher dashboard route name)}}>Teacher Dashboard</a>```i don't think it gonna work same for Browser router